# My insert statement saves same data in two columns and omits the value of second column

Tags: java, mysql

Here is my java code:

```
BorrowBook issue = new BorrowBook(Integer.parseInt(txtUserid.getText()), 
                                  Integer.parseInt(txtBookid.getText()),
                                  ((JTextComponent)Dateborrow.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText(),
                                  ((JTextComponent)Datereturn.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String SQL= "select* from guest where GuestiD= " +issue.getguestid()+ "";

rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

if(rs.next()){
    //    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String  sql = "Insert into bookissue (GuestiD,BookiD,BorrowDate,ReturnDate) Values("+issue.getguestid()+ ","+issue.getbookid()+",'" +issue.getborrowdate()+ "','"+issue.getreturndate()+"')";

    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book Borrowed Successfully");

}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID NOT FOUND","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

[This is my Mysql table output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tduC.png)

[This my table datatype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZfEE.png)

My class:

```
public class BorrowBook extends IssueBook {

    public BorrowBook(int guestid, int bookid, String borrowdate, String returndate) {
        super(guestid,bookid, borrowdate, returndate);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *omits the value*? It is not persisted? Have you debugged to see the value of your `txtBookid`? Also, what's the second update, with `sql2`, doing?

Comment: omits I meant it hides the value. the sql2 I actually have one update statement in the middle.

Comment: And what's `sql2` content? Also, can you provide your `IssueBook` class?